# PHP Number Format (Construction Station)

Tags: php, printf, preg-replace

I'm trying to format construction stationing, but I can't figure out how to get the preg_replace function to accept a variable number of leading characters. The format is [variable leading characters]+XX.XX This is what I'm using right now:

Input:

```
0
20
160
5005.5
30096.56
1000000000.00
```

Function:

```
function formatStation($number){
    $number = sprintf('%06.2f', $number);

    $number = preg_replace('/([0-9])([0-9]{2})/', '$1+$2', $number);
    return $number;
}
```

Output:

```
0+00.00
0+20.00
1+60.00
5+005.50 <-
3+0096.56 <-
1+000000000.00 <-
```

The correct output should be:

```
0+00.00
0+20.00
1+60.00
50+05.50 <-
300+96.56 <-
10000000+00.00 <-
```

Comment: "construction stationing" is what?

Comment: The next sentence explains it. The format is XXX...XX+XX.XX. It's used in the roadway construction industry.

Comment: While these codes are comprised of numeric symbols, they are not numbers and should not be stored as such, particularly not if leading zeroes are have inherent meaning, and *especially* not as floats as they are inherently inaccurate. Store these codes as *strings*. Only store things as numeric types if you plan to do math on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, which work according to your assignment:

```
function formatStation($number){
    $number = sprintf('%06.2f', $number);

    $number = preg_replace('/([0-9])([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2})/', '$1+$2', $number);
    return $number;
}
```

[Here you can test it.](http://rextester.com/RFL98329)

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to help:-)

Answer (score 1):

With substr_replace:

```
function formatStation($number)
{
    return substr_replace(sprintf('%06.2f', $number), '+', -5, 0);
}
```

Comment: Oh, nice! I had forgotten that `substr_replace` doesn't actually have to replace anything.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is based strictly on string position it can also be done without regex using `substr`.

```
function formatStation($number){
    $n = sprintf('%06.2f', $number);
    return substr($n, 0, strlen($n) - 5) . '+' . substr($n, -5);
}
```